# cross-env syntax error on new installation. index.js:23

Tags: node.js, npm

After a fresh step by step installation of Laravel.
Everything went great untill I ran `npm run dev`

`node_modules\cross-env\src\index.js:23`
`)`
`^`  npm
`SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`

`npm -v 6.14.8`
`node -v v6.11.0`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Required `Node v10.14` minimum.

You can get it here: https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/